# IE6 restrict button click to once

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-6

*** IE6 restrict button click to once. *** 
I have a button, which should be clicked once, and when clicked at first time I need to run few back-end logics(operations) for example save some data in DB, send Email, do some logging, and after the success of these operations I need to redirect to the other page.
But I am using

`btnMakeFO.Visible = false ;`

after the button's click event, the user is still able to click it more than twice. 

I have also used the:

`btnMakeFO.Enabled = false ;`

but it is not working too.

I have also used the following at the button's(`btnMakeFO_Click`) click Event Handler :

```
btnMakeFO.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnMakeFO, "").ToString());
```

I have searched a lot regarding this issue, but I am unable to find the solution customized to my problem. 

NOTE: I am developing on the Windows 7 x-64 bit machine and IE8, here the button is clicked at maximum twice. In FireFox8 it is clicked only once.

 But at the Production Environment there is Windows 2003 Server, Internet Explorer 6, at this server the button is able to be clicked even more than twice i.e. the btnMakeFO button can be clicked about 10 to 15 times consecutively. 
(The Internet Explorer 6 at Production Server cannot be upgraded because few older applications will not run correctly in the newer versions of Internet Explorer.)

 I need to fix this issue at earliest by tomorrow. Kindly help me in this regards at your earliest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW I have used the following (which I found from [Code Project](http://codeproject.com)), it is working greatly and I am happy with this solution.

```
<asp:Button OnClick="btnMakeFO_Click" OnClientClick="clickOnce(this, 'ABC...')">

<script type="text/javascript">
function clickOnce(btn, msg)
{
    // Test if we are doing a validation
    if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function')
    {
        // if we are doing a validation, return if it's false
        if (Page_ClientValidate() == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Ensure that the button is not of type "submit"
    if (btn.getAttribute('type') == 'button')
    {
        // The msg attibute is absolutely optional
        // msg will be the text of the button while it's disabled
        if (!msg || (msg='undefined'))
        {
            msg = 'Saving.......';
        }
        btn.value = msg;
        // The magic :D
        btn.disabled = true;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **javascript** approach should work.

You are injecting the code from the server-side, which can be challenging. You should still be able to see the results when you run the app and View Source in the browser. You should see the javascript in the tag, like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="this.disabled=true" />
```

For ASP.Net, you might also try the `OnClientClick` event, which you can add directly to the HTML, instead of injecting it from your page code-behind.